# Jmeter parameter without name in REST method

Tags: rest, api, parameters, request, jmeter

Hello i have GET method that URL example is:

http://localhost:8050/programs/b3cb6a0f-5d29-4744-a7e8-5fa0099dab18

Where the last String is just programId that I set as parameter in HTTP Request. 
JMeter is kinda confused and the respond in raw request is:

GET http://localhost:8050/
GET data:
b3cb6a0f-5d29-4744-a7e8-5fa0099dab18

but there's just 404 in response data.
I can just delete parameter and write /programs/b3cb6a0f-5d29-4744-a7e8-5fa0099dab18 in path instead of /programs/   and everything works perfectly fine. IMO it's awful way. I'd prefer do it with parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in path the parameter as `/programs/${programId}`.

This is part of the path and not parameter, parameters in GET request are different than POST see [http methods](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_httpmethods.asp)

path/mypage?**param1=value1&param2=value2**